# How to look for _ in a string in a column and remove _ in SAS

Tags: filter, sas, character

I am trying to do an if statement where it finds all the observations in the column "CarBrands" that have an underscore _ in the string (it's a character), and if it has the _, then I want to remove it. How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Look at the FINDC(), TRANSLATE() and/or COMPRESS() functions. Please remember to try and follow the guidelines here and provide a data example and what you've tried so far [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FIND function to check if a string contains the underscore. Then with the COMPRESS function, you can remove the underscore.

For example;

```
data work.ds;
input mystring $;
datalines;
mytext
my_text
;
run;

data work.ds_1;
    set work.ds;
    
    if find(mystring,'_') > 0 then mystring = compress(mystring,'_');
    else mystring = mystring;
run;
```

See also:
https://sasexamplecode.com/find-a-substring-in-sas/

https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=n0fcshr0ir3h73n1b845c4aq58hz.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Comment: Are you affiliated with the **SAS Example Code** blog?